# Openssh server: fatal: Too many listen sockets. Enlarge MAX_LISTEN_SOCKS

Tags: ubuntu, ssh-tunneling, sshd, openssh

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I want to create an `openssh` server, which listens on many ports (at least 100 different ports). Multiple clients would connect to this server, but each client would need to have its own dedicated port. Clients would create reverse ssh tunnels to this host on-demand, and maximum number of concurrent clients would be max. 10 at a time.

When configuring 16 or more ports, Openssh server fails to start, fails with error:

```
fatal: Too many listen sockets. Enlarge MAX_LISTEN_SOCKS
```

`MAX_LISTEN_SOCKS` is defined in `sshd.c` file. Is there a way to enlarge `MAX_LISTEN_SOCKS`, without having to recompile and reinstall `openssh` server from source?

Alternative: is there a different/better way to resolve this?

Comment: you can change the value of this constant `MAX_LISTEN_SOCKS` only during build-time. You would need to recompile the `openssh` from source.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question since it turns out that you don't need each client to have its own dedicated port, and that's the whole point of the question here. Next time, you'll get better and quicker help if you [explain your actual problem instead of assuming how it should be solved](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) — namely you want multiple clients at the same time, and ports are actually irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

You can run `sshd` using `inetd` (and optionally `tcpd`) on as many ports as you like with the following `inetd.conf`:

```
10000 stream tcp nowait root /usr/sbin/tcpd sshd -i
10001 stream tcp nowait root /usr/sbin/tcpd sshd -i
10002 stream tcp nowait root /usr/sbin/tcpd sshd -i
...
```

You should also read the caveats on `sshd -i` in [the sshd manual](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man8/sshd.8?query=sshd&sec=8).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help and for the responses, it turns out, that basically this issue is pointless. My eyes got opened by a helpful redditor [ckozler](https://www.reddit.com/user/ckozler):
https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxadmin/comments/3kdn1r/openssh_server_fatal_too_many_listen_sockets/cuwoo02

> But they'll still be connecting to YOU on port 22, the reverse SSH tunnel is a port opened on THEM to which you connect to. Your server side daemon (OpenSSH) does not need multiple listening ports to accept multiple clients. Thats the beauty of multithreaded socket servers

Basically I don't need this functionality, what I requested in my original question.